No DFU capable USB device available
I was making an obstacle avoiding car with my Arduino R4 Minima, and it was going great, but I tried to upload new code and I got this error:
No DFU capable USB device available
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
but what is confusing is that I was using that same cable for a few days now and it was working fine, and when I use that same cable on my R4 Wifi it works fine.
How can I fix this?
Thanks!

what leads you to believe that it is a cable problem?

I dont think it is the cable because it worked fine on my R4 Wifi, maybe I did something to the board to make it not work? Because when I give it power all it does is power the motors randomly with no connection to what I programmed it to do.

What happens if you double-tap reset per Board Recovery in official documention?

Thank you timemage! I can upload the code again!

It's fixed now i just needed to double tap the reset button on the Minima.

I'm voting this up to satisfy the stackexchange system, particularly where this is (I think) the first time the double-tap-reset-thing has come up in the context of the Arduino UNO R4. But, please do read the official documentation. You might be surprised how useful it can be. Double-tapping reset is something that works on a lot (some not all) of the Arduino boards.
